# What does a dollar sign means in front of a regexp given to the grep command?

Tags: grep, hex

I was looking at how I could grep some non printable characters in files. I finally found this to be working:

```
grep -c $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' *.xml
```

However, I couldn't find anywhere the meaning of the initial dollar sign (and it must play a role, as the command doesn't work if you remove it...)

All my searches were of course spammed by the "How to grep for a dollar sign", "How to escape the dollar sign" and "What's the special meaning of dollar regexps"... I haven't also found anything in the grep or regexp documentation...

Does someone know what it means (and maybe what else it can be used for ?)

Thanks !

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30904/279389. That is basically a prefix that tells the engine to parse escape sequences in the string.

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting. I had not searched in the bash documentation, as I was convinced not to have ever seen this in it... Many thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in `man bash`:

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>          \a     alert (bell)
>          \b     backspace
>          \e
>          \E     an escape character
>          \f     form feed
>          \n     new line
>          \r     carriage return
>          \t     horizontal tab
>          \v     vertical tab
>          \\     backslash
>          \'     single quote
>          \"     double quote
>          \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>          \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>          \cx    a control-x character
> ```

Comment: Thansk for those details !